# How to display geotagged photos in layout view to export in map book ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, photos, map-book, geotag

Im trying to create a 140 page map book using data driven pages and the production mapping extension in ArcGIS 10.2.2 and/or 10.3. As the image shows, the production mapping extension has a Graphic Table Element which allows me to display the chosen attributes of visible features on each page (driven by a grid index). I have a feature class of geo tagged images with path attributes.

I would like to display the images in layout view, similar to the graphic table elements, for each page of the map book, as shown in the image attached. I have tried the hyperlink and html popup features but they do not work in layout view. At the moment, the images you see are inserted individually but I have 100s of pictures and I would like to automate this.

One way I tried to get around this is to have the images displayed in the attribute table of the geotagged photos feature class itself and then used the graphic table element to display the corresponding fields but Im unsuccessful so far in trying to get the attribute table to display images.

[image: Example]

Comment: You can have image elements in your layout.  You might be able to place them into the elements.  But what do you plan to do when you have many images?  AT the moment, you have four images on the layout, but it looks like there are at least 8 in the map window.  How would you handle it if you had 20 image points in the map?  Do you want all 20 to appear in the layout?  Where should they be placed?

Comment: Careful renaming, attachments to page and picture element might work, because you can use wildcard in attachments name

Comment: Hi Fezter, I am planning to decrease the number of images such that only a maximum of 4 appear in each page by deleting irrelevant ones from the geotagged photos feature layer in which they are currently sitting in. Will try Felix's suggestion out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good points raised by @Fezter in his comment on your question, that you will need to resolve your business rules for, but I will assume that you always want to display four photos.

The solution I describe here is **not** one that I have implemented but I think it should work.

1. Insert four data frames
2. Into each data frame add one layer with one of your photos as its data source.
3. When your page "turns" use ArcPy code to replace the current data sources for those "photo layers".

I think such "photo layers in data frames" will be easier to work with than Picture Elements, because my recollection is that the latter tend to re-size when their source is changed.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, yould you be able to provide the ArcPy coding you mentioned ? I have zero coding background. Ill test it out to see which of the suggested answers work better. Thanks.

Comment: @SMAPS I would not wait for me to code this because that is something that I would normally only put together as part of a paid work assignment.

Comment: Totally fine. I actually just found the answer to your suggestion ! Id have to manually create a field for the data driven pages layer to link to my geotagged features layer but otherwise it works great ! FYI.  http://support.esri.com/ja/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/42153

Comment: @SMAPS that does look like a good solution and it's not a technical article that I had seen. I think you should put it into an answer (self-answering is fine to do).